# Is it possible to integrate iAd or AdMob

Tags: admob, iad, tvos, apple-tv

I'm developing small casual games for iOS. I'm using iAd and the AdMob to present ads. Unfortunately, iAd is not available for tvOS and AdMob does not compile with bitcode, which is a requirement for tvOS.

Is there a way to load and show the ads manually? I'd like to present interstitial ads on tvOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iAd and AdMob do not support tvOS at the moment and they have made no announcements stating that they plan to or not in the future.

[AppLovin](https://blog.applovin.com/apple-tv-developers-applovin-sdk-for-tvos-launches-today/) is currently the only advertising network I'm aware of that supports tvOS.